# Running easily replaceable water line underground

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation, underground

I'm running a trench out to my shed for electrical. I'd like to use the same trench for a water line so I can have a spigot back there, and possibly future sprinklers. I'd also like to make it fairly easily to replace if it ever freezes or develops a leak (digging through a foot of sodden clay isn't that fun).

My thought is to run the electrical in rigid metal conduit (so ~6" deep trench), and also lay down 1.5" PVC alongside it, then feed funny pipe through that. If I ever get a leak, I can just pull the funny pipe out and feed a new one in.

Any drawbacks I'm not thinking of here?

Comment: 6" of cover over top of your conduit...

Comment: Might be worth looking at PVC suppliers to try and get a 1.5" or 2" pipe in sections with a bell end for pulling the PEX water line.  The bell ends oriented the right way will make for snag-free pulling.

Comment: I used an old solid ball - drilled a hole to pass rope through and enlarge on one side to force onto pipe - worked great (and used same method to pull optical cable 200 metres...)

Comment: Once you excavate the 6" of clay, don't backfill with the clay. Use top soil, or sand, or something other than clay. It'll be easier to dig it up that way than pull new water pipe through if you ever have a problem. Just put the water line directly above the electrical conduit so you can hit it with a shovel without a problem in the future.

Comment: Depends on your climate. See https://plumbinghelp.ca/frost-line-depth-north-america/, for USA. Even if the pipe is easily replaced, a water leak can be damaging.